# why do firebug and chrome's console produce different results when using typeof?

Tags: firebug

Testing typeof with firebug and google chrome's web console display different results.

Firebug:

```
console.log(typeof Node); //object
console.log(typeof HTMLDivElement); //object
```

Chrome's Console

```
console.log(typeof Node); //function
console.log(typeof HTMLDivElement); //function
```

Answer (score 1):

This has little to do with the devtools; it is simply that Firefox does not follow the spec fully. This is changing in recent builds, and both those ought to match Chrome in Firefox 19 onwards. [[1]](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=773780)[[2]](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=807075)